Microsoft.Data.Analysis DataFrame. How to clear it? Or how to delete all rows at once?
I work with C# and Microsoft.Data.Analysis. For some reason I've got to clear my DataFrame and fill it with new rows. But I can't find out how to do it? Can you please help me?
For exmaple,
string[] names = { "Oliver", "Charlotte", "Henry", "Amelia", "Owen" };
int[] ages = { 23, 19, 42, 64, 35 };
double[] heights = { 1.91, 1.62, 1.72, 1.57, 1.85 };

DataFrameColumn[] columns = {
    new StringDataFrameColumn("Name", names),
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Age", ages),
    new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double>("Height", heights),
};

DataFrame df = new DataFrame(columns);

How to perform something like df.Clear()? Thank you.
